# can't getting the exact error in aggregation on mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

When i am trying this aggregation query on a sample mongo database of 25 entries, It works. But when the same method is applied for entire mongodb of 317000 entries, it doesn't respond. Even it's not showing any kind of error.
What to do for such problems.

```
$mongo = new Mongo("localhost");
$collection = $mongo->selectCollection("sampledb","analytics");

$cursor = $collection->aggregate(
    array(
        array(
           '$group' => array(
               '_id' => array(
                   'os'=>'$feat_os',
                   'minprice'=>'$finder_input_1',
                   'max_price'=>'$finder_input_2',
                   'feat_quadcode'=>'$feat_quadcore'
               ),
               'count' => array('$sum' => 1)
            )
        ),
        array('$out'=>"result") 
    ) 
);
```

Comment: You are sending the output to a collection via `$out`. It does not return a response. I guess you put that there to deal with the size, which is not by default actually a cursor either.

Comment: it's solved now.There is a limited BSON constraints in mongo i.e. 16MB maximum.

Comment: That does not apply to the `$out` operator as it sends the output to a collection. That is where your results went to.